# Permission denied problem in Freenas + Transmission

Tags: permissions, freenas, transmission

Running Freenas 0.7.2 (5543) and Transmission 2.11

The problem it that i can not save a torrent where ever i want..

For example...
I can save in: `/nmt/1-500gb/Tv/dexter` but i can not save in `/nmt/4-1000gb/tv/Lost`

When i try to save in the `lost` folder I get a `permission denied` error in the Web interface.

But when I try to save the same torrent file in the `dexter` folder everything works fine...

This is probably an easy thing to fix, but I'm new to Freenas.

The user name for Transmission is `TorrentUser` if that helps.

Now I find out that I can not browse the disk in Quixplorer.. 
I can browse `nmt/4-1000gb/` but not `/nmt/1-500gb`
When I try to browse the `nmt/4-1000gb/` I get

> Unable to read directory

---

$ mount

```
/dev/md0 on / (ufs, local)

devfs on /dev (devfs, local)

procfs on /proc (procfs, local)

/dev/fuse1 on /mnt/5 - 500gb (fusefs, local, synchronous)

/dev/fuse2 on /mnt/2 - 1000gb (fusefs, local, synchronous)

/dev/fuse3 on /mnt/3 - 1000gb (fusefs, local, synchronous)

/dev/fuse4 on /mnt/4 - 1000gb (fusefs, local, synchronous)

/dev/fuse5 on /mnt/320GB - USB (fusefs, local, synchronous)

/dev/md1 on /var (ufs, local)

/dev/da0a on /cf (ufs, local, read-only)

/dev/fuse0 on /mnt/1 - 500gb (fusefs, local, synchronous)
```

---

Dont work :

```
1 - 500gb

2 - 1000gb

3 - 1000gb
```

Works:

```
320GB - USB

4 - 1000gb

5 - 500gb
```

And this 3 disk is the same disks that I can save my torrents to.

Ps. Every disk works perfect when i use ftp...

Comment: It something wrong in the root folder..
if i use Quixplorer and try to enter the 2 - 1000gb disk i get the error...
but if i type "http://192.168.1.5/quixplorer/index.php?action=list&dir=mnt/2+-+1000gb/Movies&order=name&srt=yes&lang=en"
I can se the folder "Moives" (2 - 1000gb/Movies/)

so what now?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your FreeNAS web interface and browse to `Advanced > Command`.

From here, execute the following command:

```
chown -R transmission /nmt/4-1000gb/tv/Lost
```

(are you sure it isn't `/mnt/` instead of `/nmt/`?)

You mentioned that your Transmission user name is `TorrentUser`, so if the above doesn't work you could also try this:

```
chown -R TorrentUser /nmt/4-1000gb/tv/Lost
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have SSH access to the machine. My guess is that transmission doesn't have write access to that drive.

Try running:

```
chmod 777 /nmt/4-1000gb/ -R
```

That should grant all users read/write/execute permission to the /mnt/4-100-gb/ drive/directory (including the user which transmission is running as).